# Can't login in on Stack Overflow from Firefox (no AdBlock Plus extension)

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, login, firefox

I can't login in Stack Overflow using my Stack Exchange account from Firefox 21.
This happen both in Windows 7 and GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit).
I don't have any problem to login in Stack Exchange or other websites as:

- http://unix.stackexchange.com
- http://tex.stackexchange.com
- ...

Apparently the issue is only with http://stackoverflow.com.

When I try to login I'm sent to the homepage. I can't see any error message unfortunately.
I've seen other users are suffering a similar issue, but related with the use of AdBlock Plus. In Windows I'm not using AdBlock Plus. I will try later today to disable it on Linux and see if that helps.

Any idea of what can cause this malfunction?
In Google Chrome everything works smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried logging into meta?

Comment: Yes, I can access without any issue apparently.
The only problem is with Stack Overflow.

Comment: See also [SO not letting me login?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181385/so-not-letting-me-login).  That could easily be the same issue.  (If so, that question is a duplicate of this, rather than vice versa.)

Comment: I think we have a similar issue, but I'm not able to replicate it on Google Chrome. Apparently it affects me only on Firefox (my version is 21) both on Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I've also tried to disable AdBlock Plus on Firefox, but the problem persist. 

In Google Chrome, with AdBlock Plus running, I can login perfectly in Stack Overflow, and related websites as http://unix.stackexchange.com and http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. And I haven't installed any ad blockers.

Comment: I also am having this problem.  Again every other SE site is fine only SO.  I get the usual "Welcome Back your logged in as John F. Miller redirecting you." message, but I go back to the non-logged-in page.  When I try to ask a question, I get an infinite loop of redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with Firefox 22 on OS X 10.8.4 after an import of all my data (history + cookies + bookmarks etc.) from Chrome.

Removing all cookies from Firefox solved the problem.

In my case, I'm logging in SO with my Google account, so maybe removing only the SO / Google cookies would have worked. Did not use a very subtle approach here. Eh.

Comment: Yes, removing only the SO related cookies also works.

Comment: here what is full form of So ,i mean SO stands for??

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal StackOverflow.