# Getting "Adblock interferes with login, please disable it?" but no such extension installed

Tags: support, login

When I log in on Stack Overflow (using Stack Exchange OpenID), I get this error from the site:

> Adblock interferes with login, please disable it

But in my Firefox, the "Tools" menu, "Add-Ons", "Extensions" tab shows me:

> you don't have any add-on of this type installed

(It only shows Java Applet and QuickTime plugins.)

How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Um, you could disable adblock when logging in?

Comment: What OpenID do you use?

Comment: where is the adblock ?

Comment: In your browser extensions. What browser do you use, and on what Operating System?

Comment: open Id means my mail id?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Mac os and firefox...

Comment: On the login page you are given several options to log in with different providers; Google, Yahoo, Stack Exchange, etc. What provider do you use to log in with?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Stack Exchange

Comment: In Firefox, go to the "Tools" menu, select "Add-Ons", then select the "Extensions" tab. Find any ad blockers there and disable them.

Comment: Getting massage :you don't have any add-on of this type installed....

Comment: Are there any plugins or services installed?

Comment: plugins 1)java applet 2)quick time plug and no services

Comment: OK@Arjan Thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: @virantporwal, are you perhaps surfing behind a proxy tool such as Privoxy? It is sometimes identified as AdBlock.

Comment: how can i check this Privoxy in my system, i did not installed this software?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi may be this the region for that,if this is the region then what can i do next.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is this same as Fortinet Firewall?

Comment: I have Adblock installed on Chrome / Win7 and I've never seen this message (I log in through Google).

Comment: @virantporwal, not really. If you had such a tool on your system, you would know it because you would have configured your browser to use it.

Comment: closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181360/cant-login-in-on-stack-overflow-from-firefox-no-adblock-plus-extension

Comment: Opps @FrédéricHamidi ok,i did not configured any thing on system but ,wait and check my question again ,is this a problem?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you please provide a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: check new image