# Why can't I login to any Stack Exchange site with email?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I cannot login to stackoverflow.com. I am still logged into stackexchange, academia and meta (I haven't logged out). The problem resembles [Login process incompatible with Adblock Plus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus) ("the login process just spins forever and doesn't continue.") but I have disabled Adblock and it will still not work.

On an Ubuntu Firefox I disable ABP, ghostery and the enter my email and password at https://stackoverflow.com/users/login and press "Log in" and then nothing happens. No error message.

Ubuntu Google Chrome neither works.

If I press the Google or Facebook link nothing happens, and the orange "Google" part of the button is misaligned, - and so is the Facebook button.

I am presently logged out of askubuntu. There the buttons are well-aligned and at one point responsive. The login doesn't work however.

I see a single error message with F12 and the console for askubuntu: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/` that might be relevant

Here is my login screen with the misaligned 'Google' and 'Facebook' buttons.
[image]

Comment: I should note that I have tried removing all cookies from *stackoverflow.com. It made no change. It was a fix suggested at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181360/cant-login-in-on-stack-overflow-from-firefox-no-adblock-plus-extension#comment551236_181360

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your page? Misaligned how? I'm looking into the "no error message"  thing, but while I do... are you 100% sure your password is correct? If you go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login in an incognito window, are you able to log in with the same credentials?

Comment: Thanks: my store password was wrong.

Comment: Alright, so sounds like it's just an error display problem. :) I'll fix it up shortly here.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the login screen as anonymous. Thanks for accepting it! The 'Google' and 'Facebook' buttons seem just a CSS problem or something.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed up the error display earlier today. The design bit is on my list... gonna need to engage a designer on that one, because my CSS game is weak. There's a common work around ("don't zoom out") for the moment, so I'm content to call this thread [status-completed].